# How to calculate the sum of certain rows of a data frame in R

Tags: r, dataframe

https://i.stack.imgur.com/HiUcL.png

I have this data frame, and I want to calculate the sum of each year in UK column. Each year has 12 data points for each month.

How do I calculate the total value for each year in the dataframe?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1660124/how-to-sum-a-variable-by-group

Answer (score 2):

You can use `sqldf` for sum.
Assuming data frame name is `df`

```
install.packages(sqldf)
library(sqldf)
data <- sqldf("select year,month,
                     round(sum(UK),1) as Sum_UK,
                     from df
                     group by year,month")
```

Hope this will help,there are many other option also you can try like `dplyr`